# Cannot install software because of UEFI Secure Boot

Tags: software-installation, 18.04, uefi, secure-boot

When I type

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

command I get:

```
dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

I have tried running

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

command but, I get another message on my terminal.

This is the message:
[image: this is the message]

Help me guys.

Comment: when restarting your PC, open the Bios settings and deactivate **secure boot**.

Comment: Presumably you installed the proprietary NVidia drivers or something? In order for secure boot to still work, with those drivers, you need to follow the stated instructions.